# WebGL readPixels некорректный массив

Tags: javascript, canvas, функции, webgl

Насколько я понял: ctx.readPixels принимает следующие аргументы:
x - начальный индекс по горизонтали,
y - начальный индекс по вертикали,
ax - количество столбцов, начиная с индекса x,
ay - количество строк, начиная с индекса y,
format - способ заполнения массива (gl.RGBA в основном),
type - тип переменной (gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE в основном),
callbackArr - возвращаемый массив (массив типа Uint8Array, количество ячеек у которого равно ax*ay).

Если все верно, то я не могу понять, почему с данным canvas:

[image: WebGL]

с шириной канваса 1920 и высотой 1024, задавая функцию readPixels(0, 0, 1, 1, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, arr), возвращается массив arr == [255,255,255,255] (тут все верно), а с данным канвасом:

[image: WebGL]

и с той же шириной и высотой, и такими же аргументами функции, получается тот же самый массив, хотя из рисунка видно, что 1-ый пиксель изменил цвет на 255, 0, 0, 255 ?
Заранее спасибо за ответ

Comment: Проблема была в том, что отсчет координат в канвасе, а в данном случае с помощью метода readPixels идёт с нижнего левого угла. То есть если поместить на 2-ом рисунке красную фигуру в нижний левый угол, то получится ожидаемые 255, 0, 0, 255.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Размер массива должен быть x*y*4 у которого размер элемента 8 бит.
Попробуй glReadBuffer( GL_FRONT ); или GL_BLACK

А вообще ты походу 1 элемент только прочитал а не 4. Размер массива поправь.

Comment: Я итак читал 1 элемент, *4 - это rgba, разные цвета = 1 элементу массива.

Comment: У тебя элемнт массива 8 бит. RGBA это 4 раза по 8 бит.
0 элемент = R
1 элемент = G
и т.д.